# [PHP/JavaScript]: How to call a JavaScript function through PHP and fetch value returned?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to call a JavaScript function through PHP and store the returned value in a PHP variable. How to do this?

Comment: What function? What exactly are you doing? This is possible, but there may be a better way since JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side.

Comment: If you post what you're trying to do, we can help you find a solution.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-php-variable etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that - javascript being a client side technology will execute after your PHP script has already finished so there's no way to do what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: you can do that - for an example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-php-variable

Comment: technically you're not calling a javascript function from PHP, you're just using AJAX to get a PHP page - so it's going javascript -> PHP not PHP -> javascript