# Is it possible to send a value of a variable from a js file to a php file

Tags: php, javascript

I have script and I'd like to know if it's possible the send the value of a variable to $_session,

```
 <script>

$(function() {

    var delivery = 0;
    $('#jcart-paypal-checkout').click(function() {  
        delivery = $('form#delivery2 input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        if(!delivery) {
            alert('Please choose a delivery option');
            return false;
        }else {
            <?php $_SESSION['shipping'] = ?> delivery;
        }


    });

});
</script>
```

I need to send the value of delivery in $_session['shipping'],

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, use `$.get()`:

```
$(function() {
    var delivery = 0;
    $('#jcart-paypal-checkout').click(function() {      
        delivery = $('form#delivery2 input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        if(!delivery) {
                alert('Please choose a delivery option');
                return false;
        }
        $.get('putInSession.php', { d: delivery });
    });
 });
```

This snippet expects a script called "putInSession.php" on the server side, which should check the input parameter "d" and then

```
$_SESSION["shipping"] = $_GET["d"];
```

Optionally, you can specify a function that receives the result of the asynchronous request as third parameter of `$.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [How to get JavaScript function data into a PHP variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-php-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But you'll have to call the PHP-Script with POST or GET Parameters.

**Edit:** But I don't think that you can put the variable *directly* into the session-array.

Comment: is it possible to have sth like 
<?php $_SESSION['shipping'] = ?> delivery;

if I include the script in the php file,
thanks

Comment: No. You can't have half of the statement running on one language on one computer and the other half running in a different language on a different computer.