# Pass JavaScript var to php function

Tags: javascript, php

I have JavaScript function with pass one parameter to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfun(var1)
{
   var returnVal = "<?php echo get_value(); ?>";
}
</script>
```

I want to pass JavaScript variable i.e. `var1` to `get_value()`;

Comment: and why you want to do this?

Comment: PHP runs on the server. *First*. It generates HTML/JavaScript which is run on the client. *Later*. To pass data *back* to PHP you need to *send it to the server* (form post, AJAX, SignalR, etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: I get you @user2864740 my mistake

Comment: You need to use Ajax to pass javascript value into PHP.

Comment: You need Ajax or a good old HTML form : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that.

**PHP** is executed server-side, 
**Javascript** client-side. 
What that means is, the **PHP** code is executed before the **Javascript**.

However, you could use AJAX to call a PHP function from Javascript.

You can refer : [how to pass the JavaScript variable to the php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069696/how-to-pass-the-javascript-variable-to-the-php-function)

[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PHP is executed server-side.
Javascript client-side. 
It means, the PHP code is executed before the Javascript.

Here what you can do is to use jquery-ajax.

Inside that call a URL which returns variable you want.
Use that in result of ajax.
```

- Thanks