# How to send values form javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I created two files, one is an html and the other is a php file. I have created an array in java script. In java script, I create a dynamic table, and get values from the HTML file and pass into the array. Also I created an on click event. Whenever the button is clicked from the html page, I want to send a java script value or array from java script to php page.
When retrieving values in php, the values are not displayed.
Please guide me. Bellow is my code.

```
var t = 0;
var counter = 0;
var Arr1 = [];
var Arr2 = [];
function addTable() {

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border='1';
    table.name = "tables[]";
    table.setAttribute('id', 'tables'+counter);
    table.setAttribute('align', 'center');

    var row =  document.getElementById('txt_rows').value;
    var col =  document.getElementById('txt_column').value;
    var j;
        // creating all cells
        for(j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            // creates a <tr> element
            var mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");

            for(var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
                // creates a <td> element
                var mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");

                //appends img tag to table data node
                //mycurrent_cell.appendChild(imgTag)
                var div1 = document.createElement('div');
                div1.style.width = "200px";
                div1.style.height = "20px";
                div1.style.align = "center";
                div1.setAttribute('id', "tables"+counter+""+j+""+i);

                //mycurrent_cell.appendChild(currenttext);
                mycurrent_cell.appendChild(div1);
                // appends the cell <td> into the row <tr>
                mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
            }

            table.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
        }
        // appends <tbody> into <table>

        // appends <table> into <body>
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        // sets the border attribute of mytable to 2;
        var arr1 = new Array();
        var arr2 = new Array();

        var table1 = document.getElementById('tables'+counter);
                var cells1 = table1.getElementsByTagName('div');
                //var bbb =  document.getElementById('cell_id');
                for (var ii=0,len=cells1.length; ii<len; ii++){
                    cells1[ii].onclick = function(){
                        //console.log(this.innerHTML);
                        /* if you know it's going to be numeric:
                        console.log(parseInt(this.innerHTML),10);
                        */
                        //var xyz = this.innerHTML;

                        var str1 = this.id;
                        var len1 = str1.length;
                        var len2 = counter.toString().length;

                        var cell_Id=str1.slice(6+len2,len1);
                        var _ele = document.getElementById(this.id);

                        var btnOk = document.getElementById('btn_Ok');
                        btnOk.onclick = function(){

                            var newText;
                            var newLabel;
                            //document.getElementById("txt_name").style.fontSize = size
                            //var getPropery = document.getElementById("getProperties");

                            if(_ele.innerHTML == '')
                            {
                                var getName = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;

                                var element = document.getElementById("sel_element").value;

                                var selectFont = document.getElementById("fontChanger").value;

                                var selectFontValue = document.getElementById("font").value;

                                var selectColor = document.getElementById("txt_color").value;

                                var alpha_num = document.getElementById("char").value;

                                var text_form = document.getElementById("txt_from").value;

                                var text_to = document.getElementById("txt_to").value;

                                if(selectColor == '#008000')
                                {
                                        var para = document.getElementById("txt_parameters");
                                        if(para.value == '')
                                        {
                                            para.value = getName;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            var paraTable = document.getElementById("assingInstrument");
                                            var newtr = document.createElement("tr");
                                            var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
                                            var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
                                            var cell3 = document.createElement('td');
                                            var cell4 = document.createElement('td');
                                            var newText1 = document.createElement('input');
                                            newText1.type = "text";
                                            newText1.name = "txt_invItemId[]";
                                            newText1.value = getName;
                                            newText1.className = "input";

                                            var newText2 = document.createElement('select');
                                            newText2.name = "sel_invType[]";
                                            newText2.style.width = 160 +"px";

                                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                                            {
                                                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                // code for IE6, IE5
                                                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                            }

                                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                                            {
                                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                                                {
                                                    newText2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?getInstrumentName",true);
                                            xmlhttp.send();

                                            cell2.appendChild(newText1);
                                            cell4.appendChild(newText2);
                                            newtr.appendChild(cell1);
                                            newtr.appendChild(cell2);
                                            newtr.appendChild(cell3);
                                            newtr.appendChild(cell4);
                                            paraTable.appendChild(newtr);
                                        }
                                }

                                if(element == "label")
                                {
                                    newLabel = document.createElement('label');
                                    newLabel.innerHTML = getName;
                                    newLabel.style.fontSize = selectFont;
                                    if (selectFontValue == "Bold Italic")
                                    {
                                        newLabel.style.font = "italic bold 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else if (selectFontValue == "Regular")
                                    {
                                        newLabel.style.font = "12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else if (selectFontValue == "Bold")
                                    {
                                        newLabel.style.font = "bold 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        newLabel.style.font = "italic 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    newLabel.style.color = selectColor;

                                    _ele.appendChild(newLabel);

                                        if(_ele.innerHTML != '')
                                        {
                                            arr1.push(table.id);
                                            arr1.push(cell_Id);
                                            arr1.push(getName);
                                            arr1.push(element);
                                            arr1.push(selectFont);
                                            arr1.push(selectFontValue);
                                            arr1.push(alpha_num);
                                            arr1.push(text_form);
                                            arr1.push(text_to);
                                            arr1.push(selectColor);
                                        }
                                }

                                else if(element == "text")
                                {
                                    var newText = document.createElement('input');
                                    newText.type = "text";
                                    newText.name = getName;
                                    newText.style.fontSize = selectFont;
                                    if (selectFontValue == "Bold Italic")
                                    {
                                        newText.style.font = "italic bold 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else if (selectFontValue == "Regular")
                                    {
                                        newText.style.font = "12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else if (selectFontValue == "Bold")
                                    {
                                        newText.style.font = "bold 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        newText.style.font = "italic 12px arial,serif";
                                    }
                                    newText.style.color = selectColor;

                                    _ele.appendChild(newText);

                                        arr1.push(table.id);
                                        arr1.push(cell_Id);
                                        arr1.push(getName);
                                        arr1.push(element);
                                        arr1.push(selectFont);
                                        arr1.push(selectFontValue);
                                        arr1.push(alpha_num);
                                        arr1.push(text_form);
                                        arr1.push(text_to);
                                        arr1.push(selectColor);
                                }
                            }
                            //alert(arr2);


                         // Creates all lines:

                            // Creates an empty line
                            Arr1.push([]);
                             Arr2.push([]);
                            // Adds cols to the empty line:
                            Arr1[t].push(new Array(10));
                            //Arr2[t].push(new Array(1));

                            for(var jjj=0; jjj < 10; jjj++){
                                // Initializes:
                                Arr1[t][jjj] = arr1[jjj];
                            }
                                for(var lll=0; lll < 1; lll++){
                                // Initializes:
                                Arr2[t][lll] = arr2[lll];
                            }
                            arr1.splice(0, arr1.length);
                            //arr2.splice(0, arr2.length);
                            t++;
                        }
                    }
        }counter++;

            var btnhh = document.getElementById('btn_add');
                btnhh.onclick = function(){
                    //alert(Arr2);
                    window.location.href = 'index.php?btn_saveTct='+Arr1+'&column='+col+'&Array_color='+Arr2;
                    //"<?php $abcd='Sandip'; ?>";
                }
        }
```

Comment: This is too much code. Can you narrow it down to what is not working for you? And please look for something like 'javascript to php' because there are a million questions about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript function data into a PHP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-a-php-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ajax()` jquery function. It is pretty nice
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/