# Pass javascript value into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

Im trying to pass a javascript value into PHP:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1); 
    $('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($('<img src="blackdot.png" title="<?= $row['i'] ?> Level <?= $row['i'] ?>">'));
}
```

In this case, I is an javascript Value.

Here is my PHP:

```
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)
    or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)
    or die(mysql_error());
$monster = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monster");
```

I want to assign the javascript variable into the PHP variable. Is this possible without involving Ajax?

Comment: in short - no its not, perhaps some reading on client side vs server side scripting...

Comment: No its not possible, php runs ONCE when the page is loaded

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-a-php-variable

Comment: This is because you don't have a deep understanding about PHP and server-side and javascript and client side. You can have kind of relation between them using AJAX.