# Using $.get [AJAX] to pass a JS variable to PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from javascript to PHP using a an AJAX request [$.get] but am getting nothing through the $_GET method. I am wondering why the variable email won't pass even though there is a value within it.

fetch.js

```
email = resp.emails[i].value; 
$url = 'login.php'; //this file is on the same directory as fetch.js
//AJAX
$.get($url, {name: email});
```

login.php

```
$googleid = $_GET['name'];
echo $googleid; //nothing showing
```

If you need any more details please don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT I know I am going to get flamed for this but this was a typo. In my script I didn't make this mistake.**

Comment: You send GET variable named `name`. So in php you can access it by `$_GET['name']`, not `$_GET['email']`

Comment: This is embarrassing

Comment: Also, login.php should be in the same directory as your HTML file, not necessarily the JS file. Are you getting a 404 when calling `$.get` ? Check your dev console. Try `$.get($url, {name: email}).fail(function() {alert("An error happened")}) `

Comment: Yes for now they are all in the same directory.

Comment: Did you try the `fail` method I suggested? Also, where are you trying to use the value that AJAX gives you? Show that code, what you have shown doesn't even have a callback for `$.get`

Comment: @JuanMendes My colleague just mentioned I needed a callback. I didn't know though it can make a difference. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419240/how-to-get-javascript-function-data-into-a-php-variable) where I took my code from you do not need one. But his solution doesn't work for mine..

Comment: @Apparently Im user2212428 What `var_dump($_GET);` tells?

Comment: @hindmost array(0) { }

Comment: Apparently the OP didn't provided all relevant information about his issue. So I think this question should be closed as a sort of "cannot be reproduced".

Comment: @ApparentlyImuser2212428 Once again, did you add the callback I mentioned in my comment to check that it's even getting to your PHP file?

Comment: I changed $.get with $.ajax, swapped GET with POST and added a success function and it worked. However this was a completely different solution and I am still confused why this one doesn't work. I guess this question needs to be closed. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $googleid = $_GET['email'];
```

should be

```
 $googleid = $_GET['name'];
```

Because your GET variable was ***name*** and email was value that assign to name (eg, name = test@example.com). So you should access it by ***$_GET['name']***

Comment: Consider deleting this answer now that the OP updated their question, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$_GET['name'];
```

What is the line `email = resp.emails[i].value;`? Has that a value?

Answer (score 1):

Since in JS you send `GET` variable named `name` then in PHP you have to access it by `$_GET['name']`, not `$_GET['email']`:

```
$googleid = $_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $_POST for a parameter request.

For get the parameter would be visible in the url what you probably dont want like login.php?email=my_email@domain.tld

Comment: I'l have to change $.get(method) to something else. Will I?

Comment: no you have to use $_POST[] instead of $_GET[] in your PHP script.